# Host verification fails for https://www.apis.google.com/ in spring social

Tags: java, google-app-engine, ssl, spring-social

I'm using Spring Social for login with gmail account into my webapp. It was all ok when I have implemented the feature but today I'm getting

`javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Host name 'www.googleapis.com' does not match the certificate subject provided by the peer (CN=*.storage.googleapis.com, O=Google Inc, L=Mountain View, ST=California, C=US)`

This is the stack trace:

```
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Host name 'www.googleapis.com' does not match the certificate subject provided by the peer (CN=*.storage.googleapis.com, O=Google Inc, L=Mountain View, ST=California, C=US)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.verifyHostname(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:465)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:395)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:353)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:134)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:353)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:380)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest.java:84)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:46)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:52)
    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$RequestExecution.execute(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:94)
    at org.springframework.social.oauth2.OAuth2RequestInterceptor.intercept(OAuth2RequestInterceptor.java:45)
    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$RequestExecution.execute(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:84)
    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:69)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:46)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:52)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:541)
    ... 44 more
```

If I browse with firefox to the url : https://www.apis.google.com/
I'm getting the warning that the certificate is not valid for this domain.

Is there something wrong with the call of spring social?
How to temporary disable the host verification for gmail spring social?

Answer (score 11):

I am encountering the same issue. My best guess. There is mismatch between HTTPs call and Certificate. This looks like more of a Google issue then Spring Social Google API issue.

Not sure how long this issue has been going on. I started working on this code yesterday.

Will open bug with Google and Spring Google Social

Filed bug with [Google](https://code.google.com/p/google-apis-explorer/issues/detail?id=300), and for social on [Github](https://github.com/GabiAxel/spring-social-google/issues/67)

```
59:27:345 ERROR org.springframework.social.connect.web.ProviderSignInController.oauth2Callback Message=Exception while completing OAuth 2 connection: 
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me":Host name 'www.googleapis.com' does not match the certificate subject provided by the peer (CN=*.storage.googleapis.com, O=Google Inc, L=Mountain View, ST=California, C=US); nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Host name 'www.googleapis.com' does not match the certificate subject provided by the peer (CN=*.storage.googleapis.com, O=Google Inc, L=Mountain View, ST=California, C=US)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:580)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:530)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:237)
    at org.springframework.social.google.api.impl.AbstractGoogleApiOperations.getEntity(AbstractGoogleApiOperations.java:50)
    at org.springframework.social.google.api.plus.impl.PlusTemplate.getPerson(PlusTemplate.java:105)
    at org.springframework.social.google.api.plus.impl.PlusTemplate.getGoogleProfile(PlusTemplate.java:110)
    at org.springframework.social.google.connect.GoogleAdapter.fetchUserProfile(GoogleAdapter.java:51)
    at org.springframework.social.google.connect.GoogleAdapter.fetchUserProfile(GoogleAdapter.java:31)
    at org.springframework.social.google.connect.GoogleConnectionFactory.extractProviderUserId(GoogleConnectionFactory.java:37)
    at org.springframework.social.connect.support.OAuth2ConnectionFactory.createConnection(OAuth2ConnectionFactory.java:91)
    at org.springframework.social.connect.web.ConnectSupport.completeConnection(ConnectSupport.java:161)
    at org.springframework.social.connect.web.ProviderSignInController.oauth2Callback(ProviderSignInController.java:216)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
```

**Finally found solution to this problem.**

Downgrade HttpClient to 4.3.x. There is a bug filed and resolved marked for 4.5.x https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HTTPCLIENT-1613

For reference - 
https://github.com/GabiAxel/spring-social-google/issues/67#issuecomment-97154525

Answer (score 0):

> If I browse with firefox to the url : https://www.apis.google.com/ I'm getting the warning that the certificate is not valid for this domain.

The hostname must be `apis.google.com`, i.e. without the `www`. Then the certificate validation should succeed.

> Is there something wrong with the call of spring social?

Here you use a different name, i.e. `www.googleapis.com`. The certificate for this name is correct.

> Host name 'www.googleapis.com' does not match the certificate subject provided by the peer (CN=*.storage.googleapis.com, O=Google Inc, L=Mountain View, ST=California, C=US)

While the CN is indeed `*.storage.googleapis.com` there is a subject alternative name for `*.googleapis.com` which matches `www.googleapis.com`. Which means that the hostname check used by your code is wrong. I don't know where this bad check originates but it might be an old version of Java or the libraries you use.

> How to temporary disable the host verification for gmail spring social?

This would be a bad idea, because this would undermine the reason why https is used at all.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you using HttpClient. Then change to HttpClient 4.3.x library, not 4.4.x.

```
<!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```